# How to record keypress duration and send data to server in jquery

Tags: jquery, mobile

i am trying to design a mobile applet that would measure the time a user presses down on a button and send it back to the server to be recorded. The applet would record the IP, time GMT, and keypress duration to the server. this information would be appended to a csv file.

Comment: Please confirm if its a button pressed duration or a key pressed duration

Comment: It is a button press duration.

Comment: I have given an answer for your question,check to see if that is what you are looking for

Comment: this answer is amazing thank you for your hard work.  Can you show me how to send the value to a server?

Comment: @itsvector Use ajax to send data to the server

Comment: @itsvector I have updated my answer to include code to send data to server.

Answer (score 0):

I think the title should be button pressed duration.You can use the jquery **mouseup** and **mouse down** event methods to get the button pressed duration in browser.In mobile app you can replace mousedown with **touchstart** and mouseup with **touchend**.I have created a working fiddle to demonstrate it.

[Click here to see working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0yc551dh/12/)

HTML

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input type="button" id="testButtonPressDuration" value="Press"/>
```

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var date1;
    var date2;

    $("#testButtonPressDuration").on('mousedown touchstart',function(){       
            date1=new Date();
    });
     $("#testButtonPressDuration").on('mouseup touchend',function(){       
        date2=new Date();
        var milliseconds=date2.getTime()-date1.getTime();
        alert("Button pressed for "+milliseconds+" milliseconds");

        //send the button pressed duration to server
        sendDataToServer(milliseconds);

    });

});

function sendDataToServer(keyPressedDuration)
{

         //full path to your server action processing the request
         var url="http://somedomain/someproject/someaction.php";
         $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",//enable CORS in server
            data: {keyPressedDuration:keyPressedDuration},
            success: function (result) {

               //handle succesful data send from server

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
              //handle errors
            }
        });

}
```